# Zend2 Fatal error: Class 'Album\ResultSet' not found

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am new at Zend2 and i am following the Album tuturial on Zend. I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Album\ResultSet' not found in C:\websites\Zend2\module\Album\Module.php on line 51
```

I can't find whats the problem, what do i do wrong? Do i miss some code? Or do i miss some rules in the tutorial?

```
Module.php
<?php
namespace Album;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
}

public function getConfig()
{
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
}

public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    );
}
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Album\Model\AlbumTable' =>  function($sm) {
                $tableGateway = $sm->get('AlbumTableGateway');
                $table = new AlbumTable($tableGateway);
                return $table;
            },
            'AlbumTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
                return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            },
        ),
    );
}

}


AlbumController.php
<?php
namespace Album\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
{
protected $albumTable;
public function indexAction()
{
    return new ViewModel(array(
        'albums' => $this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll(),
    ));
}

public function addAction()
{
}

public function editAction()
{
}

public function deleteAction()
{
}

public function getAlbumTable()
{
    if (!$this->albumTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->albumTable = $sm->get('Album\Model\AlbumTable');
    }
    return $this->albumTable;
}    
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have not add the ResultSet class in your module.php file. add it there.

```
<?php
namespace Album;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Album\Model\Album;
use Album\Model\AlbumTable;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
```

This is mandatory to add the class in file to use it.

Comment: @gaurav-vashishtha it should be `use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet`

Comment: Unfortunately, get now this error: Fatal error: Class 'Album\Album' not found in C:\websites\Zend2\module\Album\Module.php on line 53

Comment: @Bas also add here these two lines: `use Album\Model\Album;
use Album\Model\AlbumTable;`

Comment: Yes! It works! Thanks guys! Now investigate how everything works :-)